# How to import data from one table to another - SpringBoot JPA /MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot

I recently created a vehicle management system
The system is derived from MySQL database and server side in spring
I want to create another table (automatically at runtime) that will display only 2 of the columns of the existing table.

And the question is what am I doing wrong?
Final goal - when adding / deleting / editing a vehicle, both tables will work in sync and without collisions
I would be happy for your help

Below is the "Car" class

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long carId;

    private String licensePlate;

    private int carType;

    private boolean suv;

    private int engineCapacity;

    private int year;

    private String note;

    private int status;

    private LocalDate careDate;

    private LocalDate editDate;



    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(long carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public long getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(long carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public String getLicensePlate() {
        return licensePlate;
    }

    public void setLicensePlate(String licensePlate) {
        this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    }

    public int getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(int carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public boolean isSuv() {
        return suv;
    }

    public void setSuv(boolean SUV) {
        this.suv = SUV;
    }

    public int getEngineCapacity() {
        return engineCapacity;
    }

    public void setEngineCapacity(int engineCapacity) {
        this.engineCapacity = engineCapacity;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public LocalDate getCareDate() {
        return careDate;
    }

    public void setCareDate(LocalDate careDate) {
        this.careDate = careDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getEditDate() {
        return editDate;
    }


    public void setEditDate(LocalDate editDate) {
        this.editDate = editDate;
    }
}
```

And CarType class which need only to create another MySQL table with the related columns (car_id and car_type)

```
package com.example.CarSystemMatanElbaz.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class CarType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name= "car_id")
    private Car carId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name= "car_type")
    private Car carType;

    public CarType() {

    }

    public CarType(long id, Car carId, Car carType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.carId = carId;
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Car getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(Car carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public Car getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(Car carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems youjust need  view

Comment: what its mean "view"? can you be more sepecific please? @scaisEdge

Comment: in db  as mysql you can create a view without duplicate a table  but just creating a query that expose the columns you need   ..  but 'I'm not in spring and I can't tell you how do this in spring ..

Comment: What you want to do is not clear. Why having two tables in the same database with same values? Your CarType entity has two properties of type Car, one as carId and the other for carType. Is that not circular?
If you have two classe A and B and you want to dooperations on both, you can simply put it in a transaction.Something like 
- Insert entity a in A
- Insert entity b in B.
That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of checking and managing flow on the server-side. Just create Replicated Audit Table and making 3  Triggers on the original table like "After Insert, After Update, and After Delete Trigger at MySQL level.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `db`.`car_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `trn_student_misc_fees_req_status` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  # INSERT Query of Another table using 'NEW' Keyword with car table fields. 
END
```

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `db`.`car_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `trn_student_misc_fees_req_status` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  # UPDATE Query of Another table using 'NEW' Keyword with car table fields. 
END
```

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `db`.`car_AFTER_DELETE` AFTER DELETE ON `trn_student_misc_fees_req_status` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  # DELETE Query of Another table using 'OLD' Keyword with car table fields. 
END
```

read more about trigger Visit https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

- as @scaisEdge said also create a view from the table and implement that on your spring project.

**car_detailed_view.sql [View]**

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED  
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `car_detailed_view` AS
    SELECT 
    car.carId,car.licensePlate,car.carType,car.suv,car.engineCapacity,car.year,car.note,car.status,car.careDate,car.editDate;
    FROM
        (`car`
        INNER JOIN `CarType`  ON ((`car`.`car_id` = `CarType`.`car_id`)))
```

**CarDetailedView.java [View Class]**

```
@Immutable
@Entity
@Table(name = "car_detailed_view")
public class CarDetailedView{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long carId;

    private String licensePlate;

    private int carType;

    private boolean suv;

    private int engineCapacity;

    private int year;

    private String note;

    private int status;

    private LocalDate careDate;

    private LocalDate editDate;

   //getter,setter and constructor
}
```

Comment: Using a repo interface that extends JpaRepository you can achieve your needs easily.